# Help with CAML query for accessing document types in document library

Tags: sharepoint-2007, caml

I have a Document Library on SharePoint which hosts documents of different types and i have a custom search web part which is supposed to search the library and display documents based on search type along with other search criteria.Problem is i cant search for the document type, My CAML query is as follows:

```
           SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
           SPList document = web.Lists["Training Docs"];
           SPListItemCollection objItemcoll;
           SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();
           objQuery.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"Name\"/>
           <Value Type=\"Text\"></Value>doc</Contains></Where>";
           objItemcoll = document.GetItems(objQuery);
           if (objItemcoll.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (SPListItem item in objItemcoll)
               {
                   //Binding To Grid;
               }
           }
       }
```

Im guessing the fault is with value type=" " . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>doc</Value></Contains></Where>
```

I created this query using the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx). You might want to try it. It is the resource for creating CAML query strings for SPQuery objects.